# Knockout two way binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i am trying to make a two way binding in Knockout.js, but i am not pretty sure, that my approach is the right suggestion.

What i need is very simple: 
I need the id of the binded element of my observable.

Here is my first approach:

HTML:

```
<div id='test' data-bind="attr {id: 'test'}, html: id"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var vm = {
   id: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

In the end, i need the id iformation in my viewmodel.

Maybe it´s not possible and not really reliable to knockout. But i dont want to go through the domtree with jquery selector if dont have the information in my viewmodel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want your id binding two-way? Who will change the id of the  element?

Comment: no i wont, but if the data is changing i have to do a animation on the element, which i call with jquery.

Comment: @Ipad That still doesn't explain why you need the ID in Knockout. Will your Knockout view model be triggering the animation, and you basically want to cache the jQuery selector so that it's accessible in your view model?

Comment: Exactly! my viewmodel triggers on receiving data the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give id in observable

```
id: ko.observable('test')
```

this will produce id

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9HJ/6/)

Comment: yeah, this is the workaround, but i want to have a two way solution.

Comment: can you explain? how are you going to change id attribute?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the original question, I don't think you're looking for two-way binding - you're looking for a way to cache the jQuery selector so that it can be accessed in your view model.

For that, I would suggest the following:

- Add properties or variables in your view model that will hold the selector results. These do not need to be observables, as the IDs of your elements will never change.
- Create a function that you call once on initialization of your view model, that will assign the results of the jQuery selectors to their respective properties/variables.
- Subscribe to whatever observable contains the data, and trigger your animation from there.

Here's an example of how this could be done in your view model ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wedvich/0fk5oso0/)):

```
var ViewModel = ( function () {
    var ViewModel = function () {
        // ... stuff
        this.data = ko.observable( 'No data here :(' );
        this.data.subscribe( this.animate.bind( this ) );
    };

    // This is the function where you store the result of the jQuery selectors
    ViewModel.prototype.cacheSelectors = function () {
        this.testElement = $( '#test' );
    };

    // This is an example function that will load your data
    ViewModel.prototype.loadData = function () {
        this.data( 'Oh wait, here\'s some data!' );
    };

    // This is an example function that you could trigger to animate your element
    ViewModel.prototype.animate = function () {
        this.testElement.animate( { 'padding-left': '+=250px' }, 'slow' );
    };

    return new ViewModel();    
}() );

ViewModel.cacheSelectors();
ko.applyBindings( ViewModel );
```